# Is there a Mootools ".on" equivalent?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am looking for an equivalent to `.on()` from jQuery in Mootools. The purpose is to dynamically bind events to elements that are appended to the page after user interactions.

Comment: you are after `http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation` - `el.addEvent('click:relay(a.someClass)', function(){});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `addEvent()` and `addEvents()` methods that attach an event listener(s) to a DOM element.
Check http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you understand how [Event Delgation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) works.

Here is an example from the page:

```
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ",e.target.id.replace("post-")," was clicked!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@dimitar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095219/is-there-a-mootools-on-equivalent#comment35302279_23095219) pointed out `relay()` is the MooTools way to delegate. In [**the documentation**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation) you can see both some code examples and a jsfiddle.

The syntax would be:

> parentElement.addEvent('click:relay(.targetClass)', function(){

Where `parentElement` is some element present in the page at the time the JS code is loaded, and `.targetClass` would be a class in the target element you want to have delegation for.

As pointed out, there is nice jsFiddle example in the MooTools page, [**here is another one**](http://jsfiddle.net/WW4qH/), adapted from the first one.